# How to change a function from Min(F(x)) to -Max(-F(x))?

Tags: functions, optimization, maxima-minima

I have not a good knowledge in math field, I am working on multi objective functions, and I have two maximization functions, and one minimize function, where:

- Max (X,Y) = X+Y
- Max (L,M) = Sum (L*C + M*D), where C and D are constants.
- Min (T)= T*C.

I want to turned the two Max function to Minimize function, how the function will be ?

Comment: Do you have any constraints?

Comment: @callculus, Yes X+Y should be equal to 1, L+M == 1 too

Comment: In linear programming  usually you use $\textrm{max} \ z=\textrm{min}-z$,where z is the objective function. For instance, $\textrm{max} \  X+Y= \textrm{min} -X-Y$